# How can I tunr this code into one function jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider the following snippit:

```
$('#num-locations input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var checkedInputs = $("#num-locations input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var manageWrappers = $(".manage-wrapper");

  manageWrappers.removeClass("hide-on-check");
  if (!checkedInputs.length) return;

  var locations = checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).data("location") }).get();

  manageWrappers
    .filter(function() {
      return !locations.includes($(this).data("city"));
    }).addClass("hide-on-check");
});


$('#num-cities input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var checkedInputs = $("#num-cities input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var manageWrappers = $(".manage-wrapper");

  manageWrappers.removeClass("hide-on-check");
  if (!checkedInputs.length) return;

  var cities = checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).data("city") }).get();

  manageWrappers
    .filter(function() {
      return !cities.includes($(this).data("city"));
    }).addClass("hide-on-check");
});

$('#num-provinces input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var checkedInputs = $("#num-provinces input[type=checkbox]:checked");
  var manageWrappers = $(".manage-wrapper");

  manageWrappers.removeClass("hide-on-check");
  if (!checkedInputs.length) return;

  var provinces = checkedInputs.map(function() { return $(this).data("province") }).get();

  manageWrappers
    .filter(function() {
      return !provinces.includes($(this).data("province"));
    }).addClass("hide-on-check");
});
```

Each one of these does exactly what I want them to do, with some glitches. For example if you check a checkbox or two or three or what ever in `#num-locations` and then a couple in `#num-provinces` your locations were re-set and unhidden.

The goal is to make this into one function that adds to an array of "checked" locations, cities or provinces and then hides `manageWrappers` based on what is clicked and shows those that are not clicked.

I am unsure how to watch for multiple on click events in one function, hence why I am asking here.

**Any ideas?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am unsure how to watch for multiple on click events in one function

The `.on("click"...` applies to all the elements in the selector, to select multiple elements, separate them with a comma `,`, the initial update to your code being:

```
$('#num-cities input[type="checkbox"],#num-provinces input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function(e) {
    var checkedInputs = $(this).filter(":checked");
```

You will need to make other changes to become a single function, but this answers the question asked.